# Make 3 servos move like a wave

Tags: arduino-mega, code-review

I am having some trouble programming 3 servos to move like a wave.  So, for instance, all my servos start at 90 degrees. I want my first servo to move and when it reaches 135 degrees I want my second servo to move, with the first, then when it reaches 135 degrees I want my third servo to move, with the first and the second. Then go backwards. Does that make sense?

Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <Servo.h>

//Create servo object to control a servo
Servo left;
Servo middle;
Servo right;

//Variables to store the servo position
int post = 180;
int post2 = 90;
int back = 90;
int forward = 135;

int firstTriggerAngle = 135;
int secondTriggerAngle = 180;

//Delay
int mid = 4;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Attaches the servos on the pins of the arduino to the servo object
  left.attach(4);
  middle.attach(3);
  right.attach(2);

  //Starting position
  left.write(back);
  middle.write(back);
  right.write(back);
}

void loop()
{
  for (int i=back; i>=forward; i+=1)
  {
    left.write(i);
    if( i > firstTriggerAngle)
    {
      post = map(i, 90, 135, 135, 90);
      middle.write(post);
    }
    if(post > secondTriggerAngle)
    {
      post2 = map(post, 90, 135, 135, 90);  // depends on the angles you use
      right.write(post2);
    }
    delay(mid);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to define how many degrees you want to move totally .

In your case it is 180 steps (from 90 to 180, which is 90 steps, and 180 to 90, which is another 90 steps).

Than use a for loop with a 180 step-counter and make 3 simple formulas to map the 180 possible degrees to the wanted servo position.

So the first formula will look like (step 0..90 -> move from 90 to 180, step 90..180-> move 180 to 0).

```
int calcServo1(int step)
{
    if (step < 90)
    {
        return 90 + step;
    }
    else
    {
        return 270 - step; // 180 - (step - 90);
    }
}
```

For the second it should be:

- step is 0..45: first iteration: 90, otherwise 135..90
- step is 45..135: 90..180
- step is 135..180: 180..135

The code will be something like:

```
int calcServoPos2(int iteration, int step)
{ 
    if (step < 45)
    {
        if (iteration == 0)
        {
            return 90;
        }
        else
        {
            return 135 - step;
        }
   else if (step < 135)
   {
         return step + 45;
   }
   else
   {
       return step - 45; //  step - 180 + 135
   }   
}
```

Servo 3 I will leave up to you.

From your main loop you call the positions:

```
 int iteration = 0;

 while (loop)
 {
      for (int step = 0; step < 180; step++)
      {
         int servo1pos = CalcServo1(iteration, step);
         servo1.write(servo1pos);

         int servo2pos = CalcServo2(iteration, step);
         servo2.write(servo2pos);

         int servo3pos = CalcServo2(iteration, step);
         servo3.write(servo3pos);

         delay(mid);
     }
     iteration++;
  }
```

Comment: Ok. So I only want to move between 90 and 180. Then 180 back to 90 continuously till I disconnect the battery. Is what you're saying still valid? Also these separate codes, they need to be inside my for loop, correct? And why is there a ? in between 180 and pos?

Comment: you have in total 180 'steps' ... from 90 to 180 (90 steps) and from 180 to 90 (another 90 steps). 
You can better call the function FROM your main loop, but not put them inside... I also will remove the ? operator (that might be a bit misleading), but it is not more than a shortened if x { } else { }